# Im trying to create a program that will object print a list of people that are in two different groups

Tags: python

```
class CRunners(CharityRunner):

#methods

    def charityrunner():
        print ("Club: Charity Runners")
        print ("Runner: HRU001 John Richards")
        print ("Runner: HRU004 Alicia")
        print ("Runner: HRU005 Mo Farah")


class PRunners(ProfessionalRunner):

    def professionalrunner():
        print ("Club: Professional Runners")
        print ("Runner: HRU055 Sarch Richards")
        print ("Runner: HRU042 David")
        print ("Runner: HRU033 Moe Size")

class calling():

    def calling2(self):
        professionalrunner()
        charityrunner()


calling2()
```

Here im trying to make it so i can print these two as a function but im not entirely sure how to do that

Comment: Could you explain your question a bit more?

Comment: yes what im trying to do in python is print the function so it will come out as a string or object printing?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have learned a language which requires everything to be in classes (like perhaps Java). In Python, you don't need the classes and your program will be easier to understand as follows:

```
def charityrunner():
    print ("Club: Charity Runners")
    print ("Runner: HRU001 John Richards")
    print ("Runner: HRU004 Alicia")
    print ("Runner: HRU005 Mo Farah")

def professionalrunner():
    print ("Club: Professional Runners")
    print ("Runner: HRU055 Sarch Richards")
    print ("Runner: HRU042 David")
    print ("Runner: HRU033 Moe Size")

def calling2():
    professionalrunner()
    charityrunner()

calling2()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your methods with `@staticmethod`, so when calling them just use `class_name.method_name` :

```
class CRunners(CharityRunner):
    @staticmethod 
    def charityrunner():
        ...
class PRunners(ProfessionalRunner):
    @staticmethod 
    def professionalrunner():
        ...
class calling():
    @staticmethod
    def calling2():
        CRunners.professionalrunner()
        PRunners.charityrunner()

calling.calling2()
```